# Configure Maven Java Project Build in VSTS

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm pretty new to VSTS and I'm trying to migrate a Java build job from Jenkins to VSTS . Currently in the project there are some third part jar dependencies which are manually installed to the Local Maven repository, after logging into the Jenkins Machine using mvn:install command. 
In VSTS how can I achieve the same. 
Please note I have setup the build queue and able to trigger the build but the build will fail as these dependencies are not found. As logging into the machine physically is not possible how can I achieve the same? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Do you specify dependency in pop.xml file? The dependency's packages should be download automatically.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways you can achieve this.

1. Install your own build agent in your dedicated server for your build
2. Installing/Configuring the Maven Package Management in your VSTS

### Step 1

This is easier (since this is same as your Jenkins approach).

You need to install a dedicated agent on your on-prem server, where you will install the 3rd party dependencies in the local maven repository.

[Refer here on how to install the Agent on a windows server machine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=vsts)

### Step 2

You can create your own Maven feed through the Package Management in VSTS.

[First Install the Extension if you don't have Package Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/package/install?view=vsts)

> Each account gets five (5) free licenses. If you need more than 5
>   licenses, go to the Marketplace page for Package Management and select
>   Get. Click Buy and purchase the additional licenses you need. If you
>   aren't sure, you can click Start 30 day free trial and every user in
>   your account will be granted access to Package Management for 30 days.
>   After the 30-day trial period your account will revert back to five
>   (5) entitled users and you must assign licenses to individual users.
>   If you need additional licenses at this point, you may purchase them
>   from this same dialog in the Marketplace.

**There is a good example on this by Microsoft [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/package/get-started-maven?view=vsts).** Please go through that step by step.

Comment: Thanks it helped, i created feed in vsts

Comment: @hareesh Happy to hear this. Please accept my answer,so that it also help other community members